# Adding numbers in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

In this case, I want to add two numbers in this array in to obtain a specific sum when added, let’s say, 4.  I also want to output what indices are being added in order to obtain that specific sum, just to see the inner workings of my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public static int addingNumbers(int[] a) {
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < a.length && j < a.length; i++, j++) {
        if(a[i] + a[j] == 4) { // index 0 and index 2 when added gives you a sum 4
            i1 = i;
            i2 = j;
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("The indices are " + i1 + " and " + i2);
    return i1;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println(addingNumbers(a));
}
```

Comment: I've read your question 4 times and I still can't understand what you are asking for: can you please rewrite it?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: You need a nested for-loop as right now both `i` and `j` are incremented at the same time. Also you will want to move the `System.out.println` inside the `if`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Perhaps the algorithm is to always add two adjacent elements of the array? The exact requirements are unclear from the question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `a[i] + a[j] == 4` is never going to happen

Comment: Note that you do not need `j`, you can just do `a[i + 1]` instead. Just be careful with the for loop condition so that you do not try to access an element beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer With the example array, you are correct. However, the exact requirements are still unclear.

Comment: It will also help if you step away from your computer and think through the solution without worrying about Java. Start by writing the steps you need to take **in words** to solve the problem. You need a clear idea of a solution before you can translate it into Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are making is using only one loop that iterates over the array once:

```
for(int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < a.length && j < a.length; i++, j++) {
```

In your loop you are setting i to 0 and j to 1, then you increment them with every step. So you are only comparing adjacent places in your array:

1. iteration: `a[0] + a[1]`
2. iteration: `a[1] + a[2]`
3. iteration: `a[2] + a[3]`

etc. pp

Since your array doesn't have two adjacent elements that sum up to 4 your `if(a[i] + a[j] == 4)` will never be entered and `i1`, `i2` will still be 0 when the loop is finished.

To compare every array element with each other you should use 2 nested loops:

```
public static int addingNumbers(int[] a) {
    int i1 = -1, i2 = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < a.length ; j++) {
                if(a[i] + a[j] == 4) { // index 0 and index 2 when added gives you a sum 4
                    i1 = i;
                    i2 = j;
                }
            }
    }   
    if(i1>=0 && i2 >=0) {
        System.out.println("The indices are " + i1 + " and " + i2);
    }
    return i1;
}
```

Note that this will only print out the last detected 2 indices that add up to 4. If you want to be able to detect multiple possible solutions and print them out could for example move the `System.out.println` into the `if` block.

Comment: You will want to move the `System.out` to `if(a[i] + a[j] == 4)` as you are currently ommitting 2 other possible results

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Unless I'm mistaken, in the given example there is only one solution, unless you would also allow adding an index to itself an adding nothing to an index, in which case there would be 2 more solutions (a[1]+a[1] and a[3]). But i added some text that makes it clear that this currently only prints the last found solution.

Comment: Ah, I had this initially but without initializations of i1 and i2 to -1 and the last if statement.  That's why I tried it with 1 for loop because I thought I was totally off.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Theoretically you can have the solutions: `a[0]+a[2]`, `a[1]+a[1]` and `a[2]+a[0]`. Then its just the question if you want to allow pretty much the same solution 2 times, but this is fine as well

Answer (score 1):

It can never be == 4 because 1+2=3 then 2+3=5. So it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error in your code. The sum you are checking in your code is never for. 
I added some debug output for easy checking:

```
    public static int addingNumbers(int[] a) {
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0, j = i + 1; i < a.length && j < a.length; i++, j++) {
        int sum = a[i] + a[j];
        System.out.println(sum);
        if(sum == 4) { // index 0 and index 2 when added gives you a sum 4
            i1 = i;
            i2 = j;
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("The indices are " + i1 + " and " + i2);
    return i1;
}
```

Output is: 3
5
7
9
11
The indices are 0 and 0
0

Answer (score 0):

this algorithm will never be able to add a[0] to a[2], be cause when you put j=i+1 it will always be 0+1 then 1+2 ... The sum of tow adjacent numbers is never pair.

An other matter is the condition to stop your loop must be  j < a.length-1

try to explain more of what you want from your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you over complicating this on purpose?
Trying to figure out your intention for this task.

Why don't you just do (this is pseudo):

```
for length of i {
 if (a[i] + a[i+1] == 4) {
   System.out.println("The indices are " + a[i]  + " and " + a[i+1]);
 }
}
```

Comment: `for length of i` is not valid Java

Comment: `// index 0 and index 2 when added gives you a sum 4` doesn't match your suggestion